# Dynamic Class casting

Tags: java, android, casting

I'm having a problem with casting in Android.

I'm developing an App that handle multiple devices, and i'm trying to make a dynamic class alocation (i.e, User sets the device and the app instanciate the class according to the user settings)

Here is a Sample code:

```
String Usr_imput; //name of the class
Class class = Class.forName(Usr_Input);
Object o = class.newInstance();
```

with that I can't access methods from the Usr_Input Class. The method class.cast(o) should be the solution to my problems but I can't get it to work, does the cast statement stacks?

Isn't it suposed to work if I use:

```
class.cast(o);
o.Method();
```

Anyone has experience on that?

Comment: You should be able to invoke method by name on your object: `Method method = class.getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class, ...); method.invoke(o, param1, param2, ...);`

Comment: The word `class` is a reserved Java keyword, so you don't want to use it as a variable identifier.

Comment: u ll need use reflection

Comment: Great, didn't know about this class, it works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
Usr_Input o = (Usr_Input)class.newInstance();
```

Comment: I think what he means by dynamic casting is he only knows the type of the cast at run time.

Comment: That doesn't work, i've tried it before. It looks for the Usr_Input class.

Answer (score 0):

from java doc:

```
   cast
   public T cast(Object obj) 
   blahblah..

   Returns:
   the object after casting, or null if obj is null
```

From your codes, you didn't catch the return value. `class` is not a good name either. check the comment above.

```
class.cast(o);
o.Method();
```